# Python - Change filters on website and download resulting data using button

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am attempting to download the top 100 programmes, for every week since January 2016, from this website: http://www.barb.co.uk/project-dovetail/top-100-programmes-broadcasters-own-player-apps/

To do this, I need to change the "Year", "Month", and "Week" filters as well as alter the "Activity" filter so I can get data for every week for both 'Live streaming' and 'On-demand'. The other filters will remain unchanged. Once the correct filters have been set, I'd like to download the resulting data. This could be done using the "Download CSV" button or any other way.

I have some limited web scraping experience, using Beautiful Soup and requests.

How would be the best way of approaching this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, to scrap data you have to look at the requests sent on any event by the browser to server.

In your case, if you check in developer tools of your web browser you can easily find out that a `POST` request with url `http://barb-api.mediatel.co.uk/tv-player-report/top-programmes-broadcasters-own-player-apps` is sent by the browser.

So you can send a post request using `requests.post()` like:

```
req = requests.post('http://barb-api.mediatel.co.uk/tv-player-report/top-programmes-broadcasters-own-player-apps', data = {'period':201801060107,'activity':1,'player[]':6,'channel[]':27,'platform[]':1})
```

Here `period`,`activity`,`player[]`, `channel[]` and `platform[]` names of filters which you can see by viewing source code in your browser developer tools